# Create a Matrix out of (row, column, value) triplets in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

1. What is the easiest way to convert an array of (row, column, value) triples into a matrix in Numpy?
2. How about if I have an arbitrary number of indices?
3. Also, what is the easiest way to convert a matrix back into (row, column, value) triplets?

The following works for the 3, but feels very roundabout

```
In [1]: M = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

In [2]: M
Out[2]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [3]: (rows, cols) = np.where(M)

In [4]: vals = M[rows, cols]

In [5]: zip(rows, cols, vals)
Out[5]: 
[(0, 1, 1),
 (0, 2, 2),
 (1, 0, 3),
 (1, 1, 4),
 (1, 2, 5),
 (2, 0, 6),
 (2, 1, 7),
 (2, 2, 8)]
```

And the following works for 1, but requires scipy.sparse

```
In [6]: import scipy.sparse as sp

In [7]: sp.coo_matrix((vals, (rows, cols))).todense()
Out[7]: 
matrix([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
a=empty([max(rows)+1, max(cols)+1])
a[rows,cols] = vals
array([[  3.71697611e-307,   1.00000000e+000,   2.00000000e+000],
    [  3.00000000e+000,   4.00000000e+000,   5.00000000e+000],
    [  6.00000000e+000,   7.00000000e+000,   8.00000000e+000]])
```

Note, that you do not have a value for (0,0) in your list, hence the strange value.
Should work for any number of values. 
Get back the index:

```
unravel_index(range(9), a.shape)
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Comment: My guess is the value at any missing position should be 0. Change `empty` to `zeros` to make your code work that way.