# Converting a list of triplets (row, column, value) to matrix as pandas df

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sparse-matrix

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744620/create-a-matrix-out-of-row-column-value-triplets-in-numpy), but still different.
I have a list of triplets like the following, representing rows and columns of a matrix with their cell value:

```
a  = [("g1","g2",7),("g1","g3",5)]
```

The matrix is symmetrical, so the elements can be provided in any order - meaning that `("g1","g2",7)` would imply `("g2","g1",7)`.

I would like to obtain a pandas df from this list, representing a matrix that has element names on the rows and columns, with missing values if a triplet is not listed in `a`:

```
    g1    g2    g3
g1  NaN   7     5
g2  7     NaN   Nan
g3  5     NaN   Nan
```

can you help me achieve this task in the most efficient way for huge lists?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant of all solution, but it does the job.
For your list, identify all the "tags" you have (e.g., g1,g2,....gn).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a  = (("g1","g2",7),("g1","g3",5))
tags = []
for t1, t2, _ in a:
    tags += [t1, t2]
tags = index = columns = sorted(list(set(tags)))
```

Once you,ve done that, put them in a list

```
tags = dict((t, i) for i, t in enumerate(tags))
```

Create an empty table of the dimension of that list, replace all the 0 values with `nan` and then replace the `nan` values corresponding to the right tag and make that into a dataframe

```
Table = np.empty((len(tags),len(tags)))
Table[:] = np.nan
for t1, t2, corr in a:
    Table[tags[t1]][tags[t2]] = corr
    Table[tags[t2]][tags[t1]] = corr

df = pd.DataFrame(Table, index=index, columns=columns)
```

which returns

```
     g1   g2   g3
g1  NaN  7.0  5.0
g2  7.0  NaN  NaN
g3  5.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to define an order for your matrix labels as well

```
import pandas as pd

a  = [("g1","g2",7),("g1","g3",5)]
order = ['g1', 'g2', 'g3']
```

Pivot your data

```
a_df = pd.DataFrame(a).pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2)
a_df.index.name = None
a_df.columns.name = None
```

Reindex it so that it's got the correct order on both axes

```
a_df = a_df.reindex(order, axis=1).reindex(order, axis=0)
```

Add the array to it's transpose, only where the array is NaN (in case you have any values on the diagonal)

```
a_df = a_df.add(a_df.T[pd.isna(a_df)], fill_value=0)

>>> a_df
1   g1  g2  g3
0           
g1  NaN 7.0 5.0
g2  7.0 NaN NaN
g3  5.0 NaN NaN
```